# Is wx.richtext supported in wxpython 2.8?

Tags: python, wxpython

im using wxpython 2.8 ansi with python 2.6 ,and richtext class seems to not exist as an error message prompts that wx module does not contain richtext attribute, i've searched the web but couldn't find a clear answer,therefore i come to you:)

any thoughts?

thanks in advance

Nataly

Comment: I haven't ever used the ansi version so I can't say... Have you tried to see if it works in the Demos app (which is worth downloading if you haven't)? Whats your aversion to using the Unicode version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the rich text control like this: import wx.richtext

Or you pass the wx.TextCtrl the wx.TE_RICH or wx.TE_RICH2 flag. I've heard that the richtext widget isn't available on *nix though. Did you try the wxPython Demo? That's usually the best place to look to find out how to use a widget.

Comment: Yes that was it , i needed to : import wx.richtext , it seems that :import wx was not enough thanks a alot

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded and installed version 2.8.11-ansi. `RichTextControl` is the first demo listed, and works fine.

It sounds like there is something messed up with your installation.

Unless you have to support windows 98/ME, I don't know any good reason to prefer the ansi version over unicode.

Can you provide the exact text of the error message, and a listing of your site-packages, and the contents of wx.pth